# Error: ClerkInstanceContext not found in Nextjs using for Clerk

Tags: reactjs, next.js, clerk

[Check this Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbXSa.jpg)

I am working on a project in which I have created a login dialog but I am getting an error which I am not able to solve, what is it I have given in the above photo and request you to answer it somehow.

```
- error node_modules/@clerk/shared/dist/esm/hooks/createContextAndHook.js (4:0) @ assertContextExists
- error Error: ClerkInstanceContext not found
null
```

ERROR:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: ClerkInstanceContext not found

Call Stack
assertContextExists
node_modules/@clerk/shared/dist/esm/hooks/createContextAndHook.js (4:0)
useCtx
node_modules/@clerk/shared/dist/esm/hooks/createContextAndHook.js (13:0)
HOC
node_modules/@clerk/clerk-react/dist/esm/components/withClerk.js (10:43)
renderWithHooks
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (10697:0)
updateFunctionComponent
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (15180:0)
mountLazyComponent
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (15620:0)
beginWork$1
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (17316:0)
beginWork
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25689:0)
performUnitOfWork
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (24540:0)
workLoopSync
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (24256:0)
renderRootSync
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (24211:0)
recoverFromConcurrentError
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (23446:0)
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (23352:0)
workLoop
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (261:0)
flushWork
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (230:0)
MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (537:0)
```

I need to fix the problem on that home page and give it core as per arrangement

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `app/auth/layout.tsx` and `app/root/layout.tsx` should be wrapped with `<ClerkProvider>`.

```
<ClerkProvider>
  <html>
     <body>
       (your code).
     </body>
  </html>
</ClerkProvider>
```

Comment: Project started working after adding this but I'm getting notification as below.
'ClerkProvider' is deprecated.ts(6385)
ClerkProvider.d.ts(8, 4): The declaration was marked as deprecated here.